# python Docker Image: How to execute multiple scripts at once?

Tags: python, docker

I use the python image to run multiple python 3 scripts every few minutes.  But this way I have to start a container multiple times.

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python dwhproxy.py writeweather "Hannover,de"
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python dwhproxy.py writetwitter "MarcTV"
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python dwhproxy.py writeyoutube
```

Is there a best practice to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in running one-shot python commands the way you are doing it. The `--rm` option will clean those *one task containers*.

I guess that your containers start-up almost instantly, therefore the start-up time shouldn't be a problem for you either.

However, if you want to launch a container and keep it alive, you can achieve it like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 tail -f /dev/null
```

Then you can get the ID of the running python container:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0b91c8df3d12        python:3            "tail -f /dev/null"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second                             suspicious_joliot
```

and execute the python commands against the same container, one by one:

```
docker exec 0b91c8df3d12 python dwhproxy.py writeweather "Hannover,de"
docker exec 0b91c8df3d12 python dwhproxy.py writetwitter "MarcTV"
docker exec 0b91c8df3d12 python dwhproxy.py writeyoutube
```

or all in one shot:

```
docker exec ad9ae8d67290 sh -c 'python dwhproxy.py writeweather "Hannover,de" && python dwhproxy.py writetwitter "MarcTV" && python dwhproxy.py writeyoutube'
```

or even with your initial approach while having all three scripts executed:

```
docker run -it --rm python:3 sh -c 'python dwhproxy.py writeweather "Hannover,de" && python dwhproxy.py writetwitter "MarcTV" && python dwhproxy.py writeyoutube'
```